# Date Input Field with Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Has anyone got any recommendations for a date input element with Polymer. Something more user friendly than a number of combobox's

The Polymer-Date-Picker project seems to have an issue with multiple input fields on the same page ([which I have reported](https://github.com/christopheclc/polymer-date-picker/issues/4))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible starting point is wrapping an existing date-input field library within a Polymer element.

Here's a [Live Demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/Vl3duCywfhhKGGYjVBpu/preview) wrapping [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday), a lightweight and configurable JavaScript datepicker, within a custom Polymer element.

Note the comments within the example's source code.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML import of the custom `pikaday-element` -->
    <link rel="import" href="pikaday-element.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <pikaday-element></pikaday-element>
  </body>
</html>

<!-- pikaday-element.html -->
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="pikaday-element">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dbushell/Pikaday/master/css/pikaday.css">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </template>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/dbushell/Pikaday/master/pikaday.js"></script>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        var picker = new Pikaday({
          // targets the #datepicker id within the shadow DOM.
          field: this.$.datepicker,
          // targets the #container id within the shadow DOM.
          container: this.$.container,
          // automatically show the datepicker on-load.
          // note: when set to true, it flashes for a brief moment and then hides
          bound: false
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Since this is just a starting point, you can just configure the datepickers and settings as you see fit.

Big thanks to the [Ampersand JS Toolkit](http://tools.ampersandjs.com) for introducing me to Pikaday and to [RawGit](https://rawgit.com) for hosting Pikaday assets.

Cheers!

Comment: Nice! Cheers for that

Comment: your live demo is broken